# Calling awk script from perl

Tags: perl, awk

I am trying to use an awk script through my perl script. So, when I try to invoke the awk script from the command line, it works fine as below

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

...and the awk script opens file.txt and does some calculations.

However, when I try to do the same thing through my perl script, I can't make it work :( I've tried one million things and nothing works. Can you help? This is what I'm using in the perl script:

```
`awk '-f /path/to/script.awk /path/to/target/file.txt'`;
```

...but I get a "no such file or directory". I've tried it without the single quotes, with double quotes, without the -f, I've gone in script.awk and added #!/bin/awk -f, combinations of all the above, nothing does the trick. I don't have any special characters in the file names, they're just plain names. No variables or anything else.

I'd be grateful if you could help me a bit :)

Thank you!

Comment: Your backquoted command line is failing because awk is trying to open a file named `-f /path/to/script.awk /path/to/target/file.txt`.  And that's not the name of a file.  Remove the single quotes, so that you provide *multiple options* to awk.

Comment: Hi @ghoti, thanks for the answer. If I try the above syntax without the single quotes, it returns nothing. I have to precede it with `print` (duh), as Tom said, and delete the single quotes. Thank you both :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any quotes at all:

```
$ cat test.awk 
{ print $1 }
$ cat script.pl 
use strict;
use warnings;

print `awk -f test.awk file`;
$ cat file
first second third
$ perl script.pl 
first
```

The reason your attempt is failing is that the quotes around `'-f /path/to/script.awk /path/to/target/file.txt'` mean that it is treated as a single argument to awk.

Also, to be clear, when you use backticks to execute a command in Perl, the output of the command is returned, so if you want it to be displayed you should use `print`.

Alternatively you can use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) instead of backticks. The syntax is `system PROGRAM LIST`, where `LIST` is a list of the arguments to pass to the `PROGRAM` (in this case, awk). For example:

```
system "awk", "-f", "test.awk", "file";
```

It's worth mentioning that, depending on how complicated your awk script is, you might want to consider doing the whole thing in one language or the other.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! `print` does the trick. It didn't even cross my mind. Thank you for clarifying the effect of the single quotes. The awk script just does some calculations on the 2 short columns that are in the .txt file, it finds sums and square roots, nothing fancy.

Comment: @kouki You don't need `print` if you use `system` instead of backticks: `system "awk", "-f", "test.awk", "file";`

Comment: @melpomene Oh yay!! It works! I had tried `system`, but not with everything in separate double quotes, I just enclosed the command you wrote in double quotes and I got syntax errors. Could you explain why separate double quotes work but not `system "awk -f test.awk file";` Is it because of what Tom said, that it's treated as a single argument to awk?

Comment: @kouki I've edited my answer to explain the usage of `system`.

Comment: @kouki No, `system "awk -f test.awk file"` should also work. It's equivalent to `system "/bin/sh", "-c", "awk -f test.awk file"`.